# How do I use IBM Message Broker to expose a stored procedure as a web service so it can be used with a Lotus Notes Application?

Tags: lotus-notes, messagebroker

We are trying to expose a stored procedure (written in cobol) on our mainframe as a Web Service using IBM Websphere Message Broker. We then need to be able to use a Lotus Notes application (8.5.1) to talk to the web service and get the data returned by the stored procedure. We've run into several issues:

Let me preface this by saying that we haven't used Message Broker to expose anything as a web service before, nor have we used web services inside of Lotus Notes itself; however, we've had a contractor on site that has the Lotus Notes end working. That is to say, we can successfully create a web service consumer on the Lotus Notes end and get data when using a different web service we've created in .Net just to test this connectivity.

We've run into several issues so far. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

1) WSDL Access - We believe the stored procedure has been exposed as a web service on the broker end, however, we cannot access the wsdl when appending ?wsdl to the service url. Does this mean the web service is setup incorrectly?

2) We've also tried having Message Broker generate the wsdl and then import it into Lotus Notes via the import WSDL option of the Web Service Consumer (since we can't seem able to point to a url). Lotus Notes accepts the WSDL and creates the appropriate code to communicate with it. The issue here is that Broker appears to receive the request, but doesn't understand it.

We've been troubleshooting this for weeks and have had no luck. Please, any ideas would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try debugging the web service with another application like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)? And what version of the Lotus client are you using?

Comment: I beleive his question states their Notes client version is 8.5.1

Comment: Sorry, had a week of other production issues. Just getting back to this. I'm downloading SoapUI now to give it a go. I'll be more active on this question to post results and such over the next week. Thanks for the input so far!

Comment: Downloaded the trial for this and this lead us to the issue. Thank you! There was an error in the message broker flow. Once that was fixed, it all worked fine.